# Criar um splash fullscreem e sem titulo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

Olá, estou inciando no Android Studio, e estou com uma dúvida.

Como fazer com que meu splash fique com a imagem em tela cheia e sem a barra de título?

Minha imagem PNG tem 750 x 1334.

Segue meu código:

**MANIFESTS:** AndroidManifests.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.abmprotege">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**JAVA:** SplashActivity

```
package br.com.site;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }, 5000);


    }
}
```

**LAYOUT**: activity_splash.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrescenta no manifest onde tá o SplashScreen o seguinte tema:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

ficará assim:

```
   <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Edit 1:**

no Xml do imageview acrescente:
scaleType e adjustViewBounds, deixando width em match_parent e height em wrap_content, como a seguir:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/splash" />
```

Dessa forma a imagem ocupará a largura toda e a altura será proporcional a dimensão da imagem.

Caso queira que a imagem ocupe toda a área sem importar com a proporcionalidade, deixe:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/splash" />
```

Comment: Olá Murillo, obrigado pela ajuda. O titulo saiu, mas ainda não esta full a imagem. A imagem não esta preenchendo a largura total do app. O que preciso fazer?

Comment: @Tiago, editei minha resposta, acredito que agora o problema será resolvido.

Comment: Muito obrigado Murilo, estou iniciando no Android e não tinha achado nada que me ajudasse a fazer isso...rsrs, muito obrigado.

Comment: Tranquilo, é possível fazer isso também pelo java, mas acho mais prático por xml rs

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Você consegue me ajudar com isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383075/executar-html5-dentro-do-webview-android

Comment: Consigo em partes @Tiago, preciso testar só como faz pra receber o evento do click pelo html, ja ja respondo lá.

Comment: Ahhh, estou usando o WebView no android, e acessando a URL do teste. Vamos conversando na outra página do código para ficar melhor. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383136/salvar-imagem-assinada-dentro-do-servidor