# Executar html5 dentro do WebView android

Tags: android, html5, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

Tenho uma página em html5, onde gostaria de poder abri-la no WebView do android, mas parece que o WebView não interpreta o javascript.

Existe uma WebView melhor?

Veja meu código:

**MainActivity**

```
package br.com.aaaa;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.hostcia.net/testes/html5Assinatura/");


    }
}
```

> Veja: http://www.hostcia.net/testes/html5Assinatura/

O link acima é da página de teste onde é possível marcar pontos do desenho. Essa estrutura também será usada para assinatura.

Comment: Eu editei minha resposta, consegui tratar o clique do botão, recuperar a imagem e salvá-la no armazenamento do celular. Espero que eu tenha ajudado, ou esclarecido alguns pontos. Qualquer coisa só mandar mensagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, é preciso colocar a permissão no Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Ainda no Manifest, mas dentro de application, acrescente:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Dentro da sua Activity, antes do webview.loadUrl... acrescente:

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

**Edit1:**

Baseado nesse link [Detectar o clique do Botão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075955/10526030)

Para fazer o tratamento do botão pra recuperar a imagem gerada e salvá-la crie uma nova Classe

e crie os seguintes métodos:

```
 public static String parseBase64(String base64) {

        try {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?<=base64,).*\\s*)",Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.MULTILINE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(base64);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                return matcher.group();
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "";
    }
    public static void downloadFileFromBase64(String fileContent) {
        try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
                file.mkdirs();
                if (fileContent != null) {
                    String attachment = parseBase64(fileContent);
                    byte[] byteArr = Base64.decode(attachment, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    File f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath(),"sample.png");
                    f.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fo.write(byteArr);
                    fo.close();
                }
                
            }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Esses dois métodos faz o parse do base64 e salva a imagem no diretório da camera do celular.

Na Activity que está o webview, abaixo do webview.loadUrl... acrescente:

```
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
           @JavascriptInterface           // For API 17+
           public void performClick(String strl)
           {
               //ação para o clique do botão "save"
               downloadFileFromBase64(strl);

           }
       }, "save");
```

Para ter sucesso em salvar a imagem você precisa dar as permissões no Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Mesmo assim é importante verificar se a permissão foi dada, então em sua activity crie o seguinte método:

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ainda na activity, mas dentro do onCreate(); acrescente:

```
String[] permissions = {
                //aqui pode acrescentar todas as permissões que estão no Manifest
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,

        };
        if (!hasPermissions(this, permissions)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 1);
        }
```

**IMPORTANTE:**

Para conseguir fazer isto, eu alterei seu html, seguindo o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075955/10526030) que me baseei, pois como eu havia falado não entendo de javascript, segue o html alterado:

https://jsfiddle.net/wxjkb4Lt/3/

Comment: qualquer coisa me manda email: murillo_comino@hotmail.com